# getting the rows of dataframe based on list of values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
name, val1, val2
foo, 1.2, 1.7
bar, 2.1, 21
baz, 9, 21
foobar, 14, 29
```

and so on

and i have list of names which I want to query from the above dataframe.

For e.g.:

```
names = ['foo', 'foobar']
```

I want to query above dataframe, so that it returns what are the corresponding row numbers.. 
So, for example.. indices corresponding to "foo" and "foobar" is 0 and 3?

How, do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***option 1***
use `query`

```
df.query('name in @names').index

Int64Index([0, 3], dtype='int64')
```

***option 2***
use `isin`

```
df.index[df.name.isin(names)]

Int64Index([0, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: @Fraz if this answered your question, please don't forget to select it as the chosen answer by clicking on the green checkmark.